# Ideals, closure

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Suppose $x\in R$, where $R$ is a commutative ring with unity, and $I$ is an ideal of $R$. Suppose further that $rx\in I$ for every $r\in R$. Does this imply that $x \in I$? (if so why?) Thanks for any replies.

Comment: Hint: choose $r$ so that $rx = x$.

Comment: Because one of the $\;r'$s is $\;1\;$ ...?

Comment: Doh... Thankyou. This is why I shouldn't work past midnight. Sorry for the stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

*This is a community wiki answer designed to help eliminate this question from the unanswered queue*

---

Yes. Choose $r = 1$.